# Definition or redeclaration of 'GetInstance' not allowed inside a function

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, thread-safety, singleton

I am trying to create an instance of a singleton class inside of a wrapper in a multithreaded environment. I am using the wrapper to ease my work and not to write multiple times Lock and Unlock in ManagerSources.

```
#define ManagerSOURCES() ManagerSources::GetInstance()

// Singleton
class ManagerSources :public Mutex {

protected:

    std::map< std::string , SourcesSPtr > Objects;

    static ManagerSources * Instance; // declared in a cpp file
    ManagerSources() {}
    ManagerSources( const ManagerSources& cpy ) {}
    ManagerSources operator=( ManagerSources& cpy) {}

public:

    static ManagerSources* GetInstance() {
        if ( Instance == NULL )
            Instance = new ManagerSources();
        return Instance;
    }

    ...
};

// This class is a wrapper for ManagerSources in a thread programming environment
template <class T>
class SingletonThreadSafe {

protected:

    T *pointer;

public:

    class proxy {
        T* pointer;

    public:

        proxy(T* _pointer) : pointer(_pointer) {
            // LOCK();            
        }

        ~proxy(){
            // UNLOCK();
        }

        T* operator->() {
            return pointer;

        }
    };


    // Default parameter is needed for containers (eg. insert into a map) where we need
    // a constructor without parameters
    SingletonThreadSafe(T* cpy = NULL ): pointer(cpy) {

    }

    ~SingletonThreadSafe() {
    }

    SingletonThreadSafe(const SingletonThreadSafe & cpy) {

        this->pointer = cpy.pointer;

    }

    SingletonThreadSafe operator=(SingletonThreadSafe cpy) {

            this->pointer = cpy.pointer;

            return *this;

    }

    T operator*() {

        return *pointer;

    }

    proxy operator->() {

        return proxy( pointer );

    }
};
```

I have the following declaration

```
typedef SingletonThreadSafe<ManagerSources> aa;

aa( ManagerSources::GetInstance() ); // doesn't work

or 

aa( ManagerSOURCES() ); // the same as above; still not working
```

The syntax doesn't work and it gives me the following error **"Definition or redeclaration of 'GetInstance' not allowed inside a function"**. And, I don't know why. **Any ideas of how I can resolve this?**

Also, the strange fact for me is if I rewrite the constructor with the default parameter to

```
SingletonThreadSafe(T* cpy = T::GetInstace() ): pointer(cpy) {

}
```

the following declaration works

```
aa()->A_Function(A_Parameter);
```

And if I declare it still works

```
aa bb( ManagerSOURCES() ); //  it works

( SmartPtr<ManagerSources>() = ManagerSOURCES() )->A_Function(A_Parameter); // it works; 
// the constructor with the  default parameter is called
```

I don't know why I get the error "Definition or redeclaration of 'GetInstance' not allowed inside a function ".

I am using Xcode 4.4.1 and LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.

Comment: For starters change your #define to `#define ManagerSOURCES ManagerSources::GetInstance`. Then, remove it altogether; I think this macro is going to hurt more than it could help. Much better to just make a global function rather than a macro.

Comment: I think this line, `assert( "Not recommended!" );` should appear _way_ more often, even though it's never going to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variant of the most vexing parse.

```
aa( ManagerSources::GetInstance() ); // doesn't work
```

is interpreted as a declaration of a function `ManagerSources::GetInstance` taking no parameters and returning type `aa`.

You can work around it with a `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<aa>( ManagerSources::GetInstance() );
```

A cast to `void` would also work, as would anything else that prevents the expression being parsed as a declaration:

```
(void) aa( ManagerSources::GetInstance() );
```

Comment: Solved by `aa bb( ManagerSources::GetInstance() )`, where it actually initializes a variable. I'm surprised it doesn't complain about **no variable declared**

Answer (score 2):

```
aa( ManagerSources::GetInstance() );
```

That is a function declaration; equivalent to:

```
aa ManagerSources::GetInstance();
```

If you want it to create an object, then either make it a (named) variable declaration:

```
aa x(ManagerSources::GetInstance());
```

or, if you want it to be an expression that creates a temporary object, then make it unambiguously an expression:

```
(void)aa(ManagerSources::GetInstance());
```

although be aware that an unnamed temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression that creates it, which is almost certainly not what you want.